# How control from u-boot is transferred to Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, u-boot

I was going through u-boot code for uboot to linux control transfer and came across this code.
What this assignment does?

```
kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kernel_entry` is a pointer to a function. That line does assign it as `images->ep;` (which looks like to mean kernel image -> entry point).